# Filter hash tag streams with known group of twitter handle ids?

Tags: twitter

For example I have 1000 twitter handle ids, and my company hash tag is "#test1. Is there a possible way that I can get the #test1 search stream filtered using the 1000 handle ids I had.

So the search result for #test1 will contain only the tweets from these 1000 people and not anyone else.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't limit search to a list of IDs. There are two other options:

a) get all tweets from those users and search locally (`statuses/user_timeline` 200 tweets per call and max 3200 tweets of single user)

b) put all known users in lists (max 500 users in 1 list) `lists/members/create_al` you can add up to 100 IDs in single call. Then get all their tweets with `lists/statuses`. And search locally. This method saves you API calls but i can't tell how much old tweets you can get.